# Не получается вывести список чисел в столбец

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print ([5, -24, 76, 44, 4, -16, 57, 0, -11, 98, 13, 80, 16, 30, -27, -21, 78, 72], sep = "\n", end = "\n\n")
```

Вывод `[5, -24, 76, 44, 4, -16, 57, 0, -11, 98, 13, 80, 16, 30, -27, -21, 78, 72]`

Как вывести столбцом числа?

Answer (score 1):

```
print (*[5, -24, 76, 44, 4, -16, 57, 0, -11, 98, 13, 80, 16, 30, -27, -21, 78, 72], sep = "\n", end = "\n\n")
```

потому что вы выводите массив, а не элементы массива - вот и получилось в 1 строку `[...]`

чтобы работал ключ `sep` надо выводить несколько значений и именно на это и распространяется ключ `sep`

```
print(10, 20, sep='\n')
```

Если надо вывести значения массива, то надо использовать конструкцию `*[...]`, которая и превратит массив в список значений

```
print(*[10, 20], sep='\n')
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое! Если мне нужно вывести результат данного кода в столбец, этот метод не работает( import numpy as np
items=[5, -24, 76, 44, 4, -16, 57, 0, -11, 98, 13, 80, 16, 30, -27, -21, 78, 72]
list= np.array(items)**2
print(list, sep='')

Comment: потому что вы с кодом намудрили:

`arr= np.array(items)**2
print(*arr, sep='\n')`

и не используйте вы зарезервированные слова в качестве названия переменных

Comment: Zhihar, спасибо большое! Точно, про зарезервированное слово list совсем забыла(